# How do I fix my ctx not working (Discord Bot in Python)?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I just started trying to make a discord bot for my school Coding Server. I got the hello command to work when the user says "!hello", and the bot then says "Hello @user" back. I was trying to code a command that when the user types in "!codehelp", the bot tags the Intermediate and Advanced roles on our server, but some stuff stopped working.

This is the code:

```
import discord
from asyncio import *

TOKEN = 'my_token'

Intermediate = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id=the_role_id)

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('!hello'):
        msg = 'Hello {0.author.mention}'.format(message)
        await message.channel.send(msg)

    if message.content.startswith('!codehelp'):
        msg = '{Intermediate.mention} {0.author.mention} needs help with his code!'.format(message)
        await message.channel.send(msg)


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)
    print('------')

client.run(TOKEN)
```

I've managed to narrow down the NameError to one place: the `ctx.guild.roles` part.

It says the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/lenovo/PycharmProjects/untitled/Discord Bot Pathways", line 6, in <module>
    Intermediate = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id=the_role_id)
NameError: name 'ctx' is not defined
```

I'm a complete beginner at Discord Bot programming while I have some experience in Python so help would be much appreciated.

Also here is my software:

- Windows 10
- discord.py 1.0+
- Python v3.8.3
- PyCharm IDE

Comment: Stick your `Intermediate = ...` line in the `on_message` and use `message.guild.roles`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get guild with id and get roles. Paste this line after `client = ...`:

```py
Intermediate = discord.utils.get(client.get_guild(GUILD_ID).roles, id=the_role_id)
```